# How can I backup a list of mongo collections to archive using mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump

I am using **mongodump** ( version r3.6.18) and I want to backup a list of collections.
I tried using the *--exclude* option but the problem I am facing is `OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long` which is an OS error if the argument size increases more than the ARGMAX buffer.

There is a way to backup a list of collections by looping over it, but I want to use the *--archive* and *--gzip* option on which it is not working. Can you please provide an alternative for the below problem statement -

1. I want to backup a list of collections
2. The backup archive must be a single file (gzip archive)

Comment: How many collections are there in your database? How many collections are you trying to export?

Comment: There might be more than 200 collections and from that db, I just want 10 collections to backup to an archive!

Comment: I think still there is no way to do your thing without looping your collections' name. The mongodb documentation says `To exclude multiple collections, specify the --excludeCollection multiple times.`

Comment: @prasad_ I want a way where I can backup a list of collections to an gzip archive, thats it!

Comment: @Mahan Exactly, I tried to use --excludeCollection only but it is now throwing `Argument list too long` when number of collections increases in db. I don't think so that is a feasible solution going forward. How about a problem statement, where I want to backup only 3 collections to an archive! Can it be possible? [without --exclude option]

Comment: Yes I will share a bash script for doing this in answer section

Comment: @Mahan You would try that programmatically, is it? For egs, looping over collections and then archiving it with tar ?

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately in that way you cannot use --archive flag

Comment: But when you want to restore you can use `--nsInclude` or `--nsExclude` flags.

Comment: For more info see this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsinclude

Comment: @Mahan This is not regarding mongorestore. I get your point of preparing a full backup and use the mongorestore to selectively backup collections. No, my question is regarding a partial backup where I need to backup only 4-5 collections to an archive, that's it!

Comment: Please check my last comment in answer section

Comment: You can copy the 10 collections into a staging database. Then dump that database as a single archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bash script that you can use to dump specific collections:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
colls=(coll1 coll2 coll3)
for c in ${colls[@]}
do
  mongodump --host {YOUR_HOST} -d {YOUR_DB} -u {USERNAME} -p {PASSWORD} -c $c --gzip --out OUTPUT
done
```

Comment: Does this create a single archive with all the three collections (col1 col2 col3). I need to use the `mongorestore` script too. So if it's not a single gzip archive, then it won't work!

Comment: Unfortunately in that way you cannot use --archive flag

Comment: I recommend to archive the backups manually using linux command.

Comment: It works without using single file. You have to pass `--gzip` flag when you want to restore it.

Comment: For example if your backup folder is /backup which includes multiple `tar.gz` files you can use this command to restore it:


`mongorestore --db {YOUR_DB} /backup --gzip`